# Why can't I calculate the autocorrelation function of the first differenced time series?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, time-series

I have a time series of the number of times the word 'diet' was searched monthly between 2004 and 2017. It's obvious from the graph that the time series exhibits seasonality, but I wanted to compute the autocorrelation function to confirm this.

Data for the time series can be found here: [Google trends words](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3hsfvhuxhb65ds/data.csv?dl=0). Here's a basic plot of the data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.columns = ['year_month', 'diet', 'gym', 'finance']

# convert year-month column into datetime
df.month = pd.to_datetime(df.year_month)
df.set_index('year_month', inplace=True)

df['diet'].plot()
```

[image]

I first take the first order difference to remove the trend

```
df['diet_first_diff'] = df['diet'].diff()
```

and get the following figure:

[image]

When I compute the autocorrelation function using

```
pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(df['diet_first_diff']);
```

I get an empty plot:

[image]

I have no problem calculating the autocorrelation function with the raw data (before first differencing), but I'm clueless as to why the autocorrelation function of the first differenced data failed to calculate. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post the data for `df['diet']`?

Comment: I edited the original post and have included the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Got it. The series passed into the `pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot()` command cannot have any `nan` values. With 1 period first differencing (resulting in a missing value for the first observation), this works `pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(df['diet'].diff()[1:])`.